# How i can exclude a string when using comparator

Tags: java, comparator

Present i am using Comparator  to sort my objects .I have the items in list as follows

```
   FIRST ITEM
   SECOND ITEM
   THIRD ITEM
   LAST ITEM
   FORTH ITEM
```

Comparator code is:

```
public static Comparator<PartyResultVO> sortData = new Comparator<PartyResultVO>()
{

     public int compare(VO vo1, VO vo2)
     return (vo1.getName()).compareTo(vo2.getName());
};
```

It is working perfectly to sort.But what i want is i need to put the item with name `LAST ITEM` at last.How i can exclude only that object and place at the end.Is there any way to do that.

Please help me.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add special logic for that case:

```
public static Comparator<VO> sortData = new Comparator<VO>()
{
     public int compare(VO vo1, VO vo2) {
         if (vo1.getName().equals("LAST ITEM")) {
              if (vo2.getName().equals("LAST ITEM")) {
                  return 0;
              } else {
                  return 1;
              }
         else if (vo2.getName().equals("LAST ITEM")) {
              return -1;
         }
         return (vo1.getName()).compareTo(vo2.getName());
     }
};
```

Comment: Make sure comparing two "LAST ITEM"s return 0 though.

Comment: @KennyTM: That doesn't matter when it comes to sorting, but it might be more complete to do it.

Comment: But i am not sure about the name exaclty.But it contains the word last

Comment: On an unrelated note: I was in Keppil Way last week.

Comment: @PSR You appears to be physically able to type `contains` so I assume so.

Comment: @PSR: Yes, or `startsWith()` if you know it is first in the word.

Comment: @PSR Or endsWith, or any other function String supports, or you can write your own.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Sounds like a great place to be. :)

Comment: @Keppil The Taxi driver hadn't heard of it and it was a small street, but nice apartments and a fun birthday party. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce state to your comparator and make it work exceptionally with certain values, return an integer that guarantees it will be the last one. Extended example of Keppil's comparator:

```
class PartyResultComparator implements Comparator<PartuResultVO> {
    String exceptionalValue;

    public PartyResultComparator(String exceptionalValue) {
        this.exceptionalValue = exceptionalValue;
    }

    public int compare(VO vo1, VO vo2) {
         if (isExceptional(vo1.getName())) {
              return 1;
         else if (isExceptional(vo2.getName())) {
              return -1;
         }

         return (vo1.getName()).compareTo(vo2.getName());
    }

    private boolean isExceptional(String value) {
        // is this value exceptional?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this ?

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<PartyResultVO>() {

@Override
public int compare(VO vo1, VO vo2) {
    if (vo1.getName().equals("LAST ITEM")) {
          if (vo2.getName().equals("LAST ITEM")) {
              return 0;
          } else {
              return 1;
          }
     else if (vo2.getName().equals("LAST ITEM")) {
          return -1;
     }
        return  vo1.getName().compareTo(vo2.getName());
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter implementation

```
public static Comparator<PartyResultVO> sortData = new Comparator<PartyResultVO>() {
     public int compare(VO vo1, VO vo2) {
         return mapToLast(vol.getName()).compareTo(mapToLast(vo2.getName()));
     }
    String mapToLast(String s) {
        return s.contains("LAST") ? "\uFFFF" : s;
    }
}
```